# Add product to taxon in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to add my products to taxons but I can't work out how its done. I can see in the schema there is `spree_products_taxons` but this doesn't have any model.

How do I add a product to a taxon in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I can use `product.assign_attributes(taxons:Spree::Taxon.find())`  to add products to a taxon.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **`taxons`** field under **`product > edit`** where you can select the taxonomy of the product.

[image]

You need to create the taxonomy before selecting

You can create it from **`Products > Taxonomies`**

[image]

For more details, you can visit the [**`Spree guides`**](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/user/configuring_taxonomies.html)

Comment: I need a way to do this from rails because I am importing thousands of products